# struts2 dojo plugin 2.2.3.1 and dojoType="dojo.widget.Tooltip"

Tags: struts2, struts

Im using struts2 2.2.3.1 and struts2 dojo pluging 2.2.3.1(the latest version). they are working fine now. however i need to use a tooltip in dojo widget.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
  <%@ taglib uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" prefix="tiles"%>
  <%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
  <%@ taglib prefix="sx" uri="/struts-dojo-tags" %>

  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
  <sx:head cache="true" compressed="true" parseContent="true" debug="true"/>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    dojo.require("dojo.widget.Tooltip");
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <span id="s1">Your Text Here</span><br><br><br>
    <span dojoType="dojo.widget.Tooltip" connectId="s1">Text Tooltip Message Here</span>
  </body>
  </html>
```

I got the error:
Could not locate widget implementation for "dojo.widget.tooltip" in "dojo.widget" registered to namespace "dojo". Developers must specify correct namespaces for all non-Dojo widgets -- will be removed in version: 0.5.

I'd like to use Struts2 dojo plugin and the widget.tooltip. please help
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `tooltip` as the `dojoType` in the span; see [this old demo](http://dev.calaos.fr/trac/browser/calaos_server/web/dojo-0.4.1-widget/demos/widget/tooltip.html?rev=748) as a partial reference.

There's already a `javascriptTooltip` parameter on most (all?) UI tags, although I don't if it uses Dojo or a different tag library.

Note that the Dojo tags are long-deprecated, and use a *very* old version of Dojo. IMO you're better off not using the tags and using current Dojo (or other framework of choice) as native JavaScript. The tags are ok for *very* simple usecases, but not much else.

Comment: thanks. i will remove this dojo plugin later and use latest dojo